# How to recreate apache configuration directory?

Tags: 10.04, configuration, apache2

I was setting an apache instance up.
And accidentally, I did `rm -rf /etc/apache2`.
Now I don't have any configurations.

Oh.

I `sudo apt-get install apache2 --reinstall`, but didn't' work :(

How can I make the directory again?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  apache2 apache2-utils
```

Comment: Good job answering your own question. You should click the tick below the voting buttons to accept it. :)

Answer (score 3):

I needed:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-common
```

and then had to also reinstall php5:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-utils apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Just had to think about the other things I had installed.

(Ubuntu 12.10)